# How to replace forked repository on my local machine?

Tags: git, github

I have a folder called "firestorm" that is pulled from the master branch, but I'm trying to replace it with the folder "firestorm" that points at my clone so that I can create a pull request.  I can't `rm -r` the folder (as it is write-protected), and I can't just pull mine down since it runs into a naming error.

Answer (score 0):

You can `git clone <repo-url> <directory-name>` to clone the repo to whatever directory you'd like.